# Why am I getting an invalid character constant for the '[ in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

There is an issue with for the '[ right in front of the data-testing-id and I am not sure why. Any help is appreciated.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1001; i = i + 1) {

        if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('[data-testing-id="data-id1"]'))!= null){
            System.out.println("Element is Present");
            }else{
            System.out.println("Element is Absent");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's the difference between `'` and `"`?

Comment: in java string must be enclosed with double quote `"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java String(s) can't be done in single quotes. This,

```
By.cssSelector('[data-testing-id="data-id1"]')
```

Should be (escaping the double quotes),

```
By.cssSelector("[data-testing-id=\"data-id1\"]")
```

or with single quotes inside the double quotes, like

```
By.cssSelector("[data-testing-id='data-id1']")
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up... if I want to increment through 1000x, do you know what am I doing wrong with this syntax? for (int i = 1; i < 1001; i = i + 1) {
  
  if(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-testing-id=\"data-id+i+\"]"))!= null)

Comment: Since it's in quotes, you're getting a literal `+i+` in your `String` (and you should probably have used a debugger). `String.format("[data-testing-id=\"data-id%d\"]", i)`

Comment: Thanks again for following up. I am sure that is the best way to do it. It isn't working with my Selenium code so I think I'll have to go a different route. Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> "[data-testing-id=\"data-id1\"]"

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 1; i < 1001; i++)
```

i++ is another way to add an increment of 1 to i for each loop... And a wee bit easier than typing  (i = i + 1)

I am new to Java and not sure if that was worth your time reading, but I think its pretty cool and might make your code prettier...